# AES-128 encryption in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have tried to encrypt some plaintext, which is in bytes, with a key, which is in bytes. However, the output I am getting is not what I am expecting.

```
public class AES {


    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
            return cipherText;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String byteToHex(byte[] hash) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hash.length * 2);
        for (byte b : hash) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        byte plaintext[] = {0x00,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,0x58,0x63,(byte)0xaa,(byte)0xbb,(byte)0xcc,(byte)0xdd,(byte)0xee,(byte)0xff};
        byte key[] = {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0a,0x0b,0x0c,0x0d,0x0e,0x0f};


        byte[] encrypted = encrypt(plaintext, key);
        System.out.println("Encrypted String : " + byteToHex(encrypted));

    }
}
```

The output I am getting is: `814064943fe05668da1f3d2269a4ee22954f64f2e4e86e9eee82d20216684899` while I am expecting `69c4e0d86a7b0430d8cdb78070b4c55a`. I am using the plaintext and key from [here](http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/AES-Example-Vector-of-AES-Encryption.html)

Comment: Do you understand what PKCS5 padding does? A hint: I will always make the result longer. So an input of 16 bytes can never result in an output of 16 bytes.

Comment: No, I have removed it, and use the default. However, I would like to know why I am getting the incorrect output

Comment: I have also tried to print the encrypted byte array with `Array.toString(encrypted )`

Comment: The default padding mode of your AES provider is most likely "PKCS5". So you haven't changed anything... Read about it and you have a good idea why your result is different.

Comment: Have read about it, and I found out that I had to use NoPadding, which has given me the proper format. However, I am still getting the incorrect output.

Comment: BTW, I am getting different cipher texts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things incorrect in your code.

1. You use PKCS5 padding while the original example doesn't use any padding.
2. You incorrectly copied the plain text.

So:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");

...

byte plaintext[] = { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, (byte) 0x88,
        (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0xbb, (byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0xff };
```

Result:

```
Encrypted String : 69c4e0d86a7b0430d8cdb78070b4c55a
```